# Discord.Py send message on reaction

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Since `on_reaction_add()` only takes 2 arguments which are "`reaction`" and "`user`" how am I supposed to send a message if I can't pass in `ctx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
channel = reaction.message.channel
await channel.send("text")
```